# Bioinformatics add-on for Orange 3.13

Tags: orange

I am using Orange 3.13 on Windows 8.1 Enterprise. I successfully added add-on Bioinformatics, however I am missing some of the widgets in this add-on. I would need PIPAx, Volcano plot, Set enrichment, Select genes, BioMart, and Gene info. But some other widgets are also missing.

Could anyone tell me if this is due technical limitations on my side or due to some updates/removal of some widgets etc.?

And if I can find the missing widgets or similar ones for Orange somewhere else?

Thank you very much.

Kind regards, Ana :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a two version of the bioinformatics add-on, version 3 and 2. Your installed the newer add-on, which has less widgets.

To get the older version, open the add-on dialog, click "Add more..." button and type "orange-bioinformatics" into the box. Then, a new add-on (version 2) will appear on the list of add-ons. Now you can choose to install it.